# С++ _TCHAR szTestString[] Как присвоить значение строки

Tags: c++, строки

Вот так работает `_TCHAR szTestString[] = _T("132.423.432:8181");`
А как присвоить string, пишет ошибку "для агрегатного объекта требуется инициализация с использованием {...}"

Comment: Используйте `std::string`

Comment: @dIm0n как ?  Ничего не получается.

Comment: Вместо `_TCHAR` и `_T` везде `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно из `_TCHAR` в `std::string`, тогда как-то так

```
    _TCHAR tstr[] = _T("132.423.432:8181");
    std::string str(tstr, tstr + sizeof(tstr) / sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Если вам нужно `"132.423.432:8181"` в `std::string`, тогда так

```
    std::string str("132.423.432:8181");
```

Answer (score 0):

В зависимости от настроек использования Юникода в проекте запись

```cpp
_TCHAR szTestString[] = _T("132.423.432:8181");
```

разворачивается препроцессором в

```cpp
char szTestString[] = "132.423.432:8181";     // без Unicode
wchar_t szTestString[] = L"132.423.432:8181"; // c Unicode
```

Если уже имеется объект `std::string` или `std::wstring`, то поступить можно двумя способами:

- Получить указатель на низлежащую строку, вызвав метод `c_str()`
- Скопировать содержимое строчки в массив на стеке, если вдруг он позарез нужен:

```cpp
char szTestString[18] = { 0 };
strcpy_s(szTestString, sMyStdString.c_str());

// или

wchar_t szTestString[18] = { 0 };
wcscpy_s(szTestString, sMyStdWstring.c_str());
```

Если же нужно попросту инициализировать строку, то никто не мешает сделать так:

```cpp
std::string str = "132.423.432:8181";
std::wstring wstr = L"132.423.432:8181";
```

Ну либо так:

```cpp
#ifdef UNICODE // возможно _UNICODE
#   define tstring wstring
#else
#   define tstring string
#endif

// ...

std::tstring str = _T("132.423.432:8181");
```

PS: по поводу `std::string` везде и всюду - в программировании под Windows - не самая лучшая практика. Как минимум по причине повсеместного использования юникода в винде - тогда уж `std::wstring` лучше, но и тут есть свой минус - `std::basic_string` - штука довольно медленная (по крайней мере в реализации STL от Microsoft, поэтому если важна производительность, то лучше оперировать голыми строчками. Однако, если производительность не сильно важна, то можно и их использовать, но надо помнить, что WinAPI - штука сишная, там нужно часть будет звать методы `c_str()` и `data()`, а также помнить, что при изменении размера строки адрес внутренней сишной строчки меняется и инвалидирует полученные ранее указатели на неё.

Comment: *"`std::string` везде и всюду - в программировании под Windows - не самая лучшая практика"* — http://utf8everywhere.org/